# What do you mean by mac restarted: previous shutdown cause: -20

Tags: macos, logging

I'm using macs as servers.

I found that the mac has been restarted according to:

```
last reboot
```

Returns

> reboot ~.        Sun Aug 2 23:19

While looking into logs

```
log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 13h
```

I see

```
Timestamp           Thread Type    Activity PID TTL
2020-08-02 23:19:53 0xc3   Default 0x0      0   0   kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -20
```

What does shutdown cause -20 mean?

Comment: isn't' this more suited @ [Superuser.SE] ?

Comment: apple.stackexchange.com actually

Comment: http://serverfault.com probably

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the list of all shutdown causes [here](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/)

-20:

```
  BridgeOS T2-initiated shutdown. -  The T2 chip in your 2018+ MacBook Pro or other Mac  initiated a shutdown.
```